# Convert IQueryable<> type object to List<T> type?

Tags: c#, list, iqueryable

I have `IQueryable<>` object.

I want to Convert it into `List<>` with selected columns like `new { ID = s.ID, Name = s.Name }`.

Edited

Marc you are absolutely right!

but I have only access to `FindByAll()` Method (because of my architecture).

And it gives me whole object in `IQueryable<>`

And I have strict requirement( for creating json object for select tag) to have only `list<>` type with two fields.

Comment: So what fails if you use FindByAll(...).Select(s=>new {ID = s.ID, Name = s.Name}).ToList()?

Comment: Note also the comment under my answer about creating your own type if needed. Json.NET might demand editable properties, in which case you'll need your own type (C# anonymous types are immutable).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Then just `Select`:

```
var list = source.Select(s=>new { ID = s.ID, Name = s.Name }).ToList();
```

(edit) Actually - the names could be inferred in this case, so you could use:

```
var list = source.Select(s=>new { s.ID, s.Name }).ToList();
```

which saves a few electrons...

Comment: As per my Tier, I can only get the whole object by linq query.

that's the problem

Comment: Can you explain? I don't understand the comment.

Comment: If you mean you need to return this object between tiers, then you'll need to create a regular type with an ID and Name, and Select(s=>new YourType {ID = s.ID, Name = s.Name }).ToList();

Comment: @Brij what issue? it is very unclear; it looks like the main problem in your code is that `ToList()` will return a `List<T>`, not an `ArrayList` - I suspect simply using `var data = ....` should be your first step.

Answer (score 53):

Add the following:

```cs
using System.Linq
```

...and call `ToList()` on the `IQueryable<>`.

Comment: @pauliephonic you should start using (pun intended) ReSharper, then you'll never have to type another using statement again ;-)

Comment: Simple, precise, beautiful!

Answer (score 8):

The List class's constructor can convert an IQueryable for you:

```
public static List<TResult> ToList<TResult>(this IQueryable source)
{
    return new List<TResult>(source);
}
```

or you can just convert it without the extension method, of course:

```
var list = new List<T>(queryable);
```

Comment: Your welcome. I really wonder why this extension wasn't included in .NET to begin with...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What do you mean by "why this extension wasn't included ..."? It's working though.

Comment: I mean the IQueryable.ToList() should really already be there, it's silly that we need to add it as an extension ourselves.

Answer (score 6):

System.Linq has ToList() on IQueryable<> and IEnumerable<>.  It will cause a full pass through the data to put it into a list, though.  You loose your deferred invoke when you do this.  Not a big deal if it is the consumer of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of extension methods I've jury-rigged together to convert IQueryables and IEnumerables from one type to another (i.e. DTO). It's mainly used to convert from a larger type (i.e. the type of the row in the database that has unneeded fields) to a smaller one.

The positive sides of this approach are:

- it requires almost no code to use - a simple call to .Transform`<DtoType>`() is all you need
- it works just like .Select(s=>new{...}) i.e. when used with IQueryable it produces the optimal SQL code, excluding Type1 fields that DtoType doesn't have.

LinqHelper.cs:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Transform<TResult>(this IQueryable source)
{
    var resultType = typeof(TResult);
    var resultProperties = resultType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite);

    ParameterExpression s = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "s");

    var memberBindings =
        resultProperties.Select(p =>
            Expression.Bind(typeof(TResult).GetMember(p.Name)[0], Expression.Property(s, p.Name))).OfType<MemberBinding>();

    Expression memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(
        Expression.New(typeof(TResult)),
        memberBindings
        );

    var memberInitLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberInit, s);

    var typeArgs = new[]
        {
            source.ElementType, 
            memberInit.Type
        };

    var mc = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", typeArgs, source.Expression, memberInitLambda);

    var query = source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(mc);

    return query;
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Transform<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    return source.AsQueryable().Transform<TResult>();
}
```

Comment: For people comming from Hibernate/NHibernate worlds to Linq: the functionality is about the same as NHibernate's **.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(DtoType)))** or Hibernate's **.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DtoType.class))**