# How to get IQueryable.ToList() with database fieldnames instead of entity properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, reporting-services, linq-to-entities

The scenario:

1. I have a considerable amount of entities as models in CodeFirst mapped to the database fieldname with the Attribute `[Column("str")]`.
2. I have a bunch of Reporting Service Reports (in local-mode) with the DataSets mapped to the database field names.

I can't pass direct results of linq queries to those reports with the ToList() method because of the field names. What I can do (and I'm trying to avoid) is to type `select new` for each object; or run each query via a different datasource.

Question:

I would like to know if there is any trick to have a IQueryable object with the *original* field names instead of the property names. Something like a ***dynamic `select new`***.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Just see of this is of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755826/convert-iqueryable-type-object-to-listt-type

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't different from what I'm doing. I just was wondering if there were a trick  for EntityFramework to retrieve the original field names instead of the entity properties.

Comment: No, there isn't. The database column names either have to match the property name, or you have to use the `Column` attribute to make them line up. That's your only choices.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisPratt. I think you should post that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. The database column names either have to match the property name, or you have to use the `Column` attribute to make them line up. That's your only choices.

Comment: I had an uncommon scenario that must be avoided, anyway. Thanks.