# System.NotSupportedException: 'Store does not implement IQueryableUserStore<TUser>.':Getting List of Users (Custom Identity: JSON file)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to retrieve a list of users from custom DB (JSON File)

[This is the project that I've used to implemented the work project](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb).

Now, I've tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755826/convert-iqueryable-type-object-to-listt-type).

But I'm still getting an error in the Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/Users
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        var List = UserManager.Users.Select(s => new { ID = s.Id, Name = s.UserName }).ToList();

        return View(List);
    }
```

And here is my Implementation of the UserStore

```
public class UserStore : 
    IUserStore<User, int>, 
    IUserPasswordStore<User, int>, 
    IUserLockoutStore<User, int>, 
    IUserTwoFactorStore<User, int>,
    IUserRoleStore<User, int>,
    IUserClaimStore<User, int>,
    IUserLoginStore<User, int>
```

I've tried to implement the Interface of IQueryableUserStore and implement the associated methods but the class is throwing 3 compile errors

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0311  The type 'EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IQueryableUserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity.User' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.  EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity C:\Users\nbinobied\Desktop\Raqeb\EjadahDashbord\Custom.Auth\UserStore.cs    13  Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0311  The type 'EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IUserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity.User' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.   EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity C:\Users\nbinobied\Desktop\Raqeb\EjadahDashbord\Custom.Auth\UserStore.cs    13  Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0311  The type 'EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IQueryableUserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity.User' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.    EjadahDashboard.Custom.Identity C:\Users\nbinobied\Desktop\Raqeb\EjadahDashbord\Custom.Auth\UserStore.cs    13  Active

**Update:**

> I was able to solve this issue by implementing `IQueryableUserStore<User, int>` into the UserStore and implementing the method
>
> `public IQueryable<User> Users => (UserDb.TryLoadData()).AsQueryable();`
>
> then call the `var List = UserManager.Users.ToList();` in the controller.

Comment: On first glance, it looks like your `User` class does not implement the required `IUser` interface. I cannot be sure, though, since you did not post the relevant code.